# Why has netty of unspecified version shaded into jar?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

The netty version is declared in pom file.

```
<netty.version>4.0.36.Final</netty.version>
```

The shade plugin of maven is also declared as following:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>client</artifact>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </filter>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>io.Client</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>      
  </plugin>
```

*But, i found another version of netty was included from compiled log*. I can not understand this situation.

```
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade (default) @ client ---
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.36.Final in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including io.netty:netty:jar:3.7.0.Final in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.0 in the shaded jar.
```

Comment: could you share your netty dependency block from pom as well

Answer (score 1):

You can analyze your project's dependency tree to get to know the source of `io.netty:netty` artifact using -

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Just to reproduce using the specified version and artifact as in your logs -

> Including io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.36.Final

The following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.36.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

results into a sample log as follows for me -

> ```
> [INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade (default) @ netty-sample --- 
> [INFO] Including io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.36.Final in the shaded jar.
>
> [INFO] No artifact matching filter client
> ```

***Note***: There is no `io.netty:netty:jar:3.7.0.Final` in the logs.

Comment: Thx, i used command `mvn dependency:tree` to check dependency, then i found the some jar depend `io.netty:netty:jar:3.7.0.Final`, so this version of netty is brought in.

Comment: Cool, that should help I guess. :)

Comment: I was not clear on what is done. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: @NagireddyHanisha There were two versions of the same dependency getting resolved in the same project. The `dependency:tree` command lets you figure out the sources and their tree.

Comment: Ok, how have you discovered which two were responsible for conflicting versions? I also have the same problem netty conflict .. I have 4.1.14 and not sure from where netty:jar 3.8.0 is coming.